# Why is this code running slow?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, performance, cocoa, ipad

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out why this code is running slow. What I'm doing below is getting JSON data from yahoo finance for 4 companies. From the JSON data I'm simply extracting the names of the 4 companies. However as I NSLog the names of the 4 companies it takes almost 2 full seconds to do so! Is their something in the code that I'm doing wrong? how can I get the code to run faster?

```
for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    //download JSON data
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: 
                    [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22AAPL%22,%22GOOG%22,%22GE%22,%22MCD%22)%0A%09%09&env=http%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltables.env&format=json"]];

    //parse out the json data
    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization 
                          JSONObjectWithData:data //1

                          options:kNilOptions 
                          error:&error];

    //Get the relavent data from JSON
    NSString* companyName = [[[[[json objectForKey:@"query"] objectForKey:@"results"] objectForKey:@"quote"] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Name"] ;

    NSLog(@"company name is %@", companyName);
}
```

Comment: You are doing several things that are slow here: `NSURLRequest` and `NSJSONSerialization`, Why are you doing them all 4 times, instead of caching the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Richard said, don't download the file 4 times. As a first iteration try this:

```
   //download JSON data
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: 
                    [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22AAPL%22,%22GOOG%22,%22GE%22,%22MCD%22)%0A%09%09&env=http%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltables.env&format=json"]];

    //parse out the json data
    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization 
                          JSONObjectWithData:data //1

                          options:kNilOptions 
                          error:&error];

for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {

    //Get the relavent data from JSON
    NSString* companyName = [[[[[json objectForKey:@"query"] objectForKey:@"results"] objectForKey:@"quote"] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Name"] ;

    NSLog(@"company name is %@", companyName);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It makes sense, I dont know why I didn't do that before.

Answer (score 1):

`NSLog` will slow an app down, and the data request method `+dataWithContentsOfURL:` is synchronous, which means your app sits there and waits for a response to come back before going through the rest of the loop.

Use an [asynchronous request](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsurlconnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to get network data, putting your JSON-parsing code into the delegate method that handles the response. This will make the app appear to run faster, by processing results as soon as they come in.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  Although DrummerB's response does raise a valid point, which is that OP is downloading the same data multiple times, it's more important to do this kind of processing in a background thread so the UI doesn't appear unresponsive.